# two controllers inside one module not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to print scope value from 2 controllers. It is not printing the value from the second controller. What is my mistake?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
{{carname}}
</div>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl2">
{{carname}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Honda";
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Toyota";
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have two apps defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined two `ng-app`, angular will bootstrap the first app it finds on the page and not the second one. Therefore second one doesn't work.

Define app on the element covering all the controller elements.

Example Snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {
  $scope.carname = "Honda";
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
  $scope.carname = "Toyota";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    {{carname}}
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    {{carname}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two `ng-app` on single page doesn't work, it will compile only the 1st instance of `ng-app` and the other will get ignored.

It seems like you wanted to use two controllers on the same page. What you can do is you can move `ng-app` directive on body level & have `ng-controller` on two different divs.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    {{carname}}
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    {{carname}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need ng-app for each div, change your html like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
       {{carname}}
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
         {{carname}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you defined your app twice. Try to use this code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div  ng-controller="Ctrl1">
  {{carname}}
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
  {{carname}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Honda";
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Toyota";
});
</script>
```